# Parameters can not be read from an Ajax get request in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, parameters

I am trying to send a longitude and latitude from my view to my controller. However it is not being picked up in my controller.

Here is the view

```
        fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${query}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9ubnlwZWluIiwiYSI6ImNrN2c3aDFjZjA4OG4zZW8yZ3ozcjF4bWQifQ.8PT8uVs7CsaJU5PNDLZdHw`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const lon = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
        const lat = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
         displayMap(lat, lon);

         $.ajax({
          url: "/set_location",
          data: {"lon": lon, "lat": lat},
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
      });
      });

      };


      // Event Trigger
      submit.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const input = document.querySelector('.form-control');
        fetchMap(input.value);
      });

submit.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const input = document.querySelector('.form-control');
        fetchMap(input.value);
      });
```

The controller is below

```
def set_location
    Client.last.lat = params[:lat]
    Client.last.lon = params[:lon]

    { 'lat': params[:lat], 'lon': params[:lon] }
  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: can you add the complete log of the ajax requesting to the api.

Comment: Can you please clarify what are you trying to do? What does not work? Do you see lat/lon in JS console in success callback? Or do you expect client record to be updated in DB?

Comment: The console log prints undefined so not the success callback function is not working. I am trying to send a ajax request to my controller so I can save the lon and lat into my DB